# Scroll horizontalScrollView left-right

Tags: android, horizontal-scrolling

I'm using HorizontalScrollView for show header in my app,I also need to scroll header left-right on clicking on left-right button.I have used some code that is working successfully in scrolling right-to-left but i'm unable to scroll left-to-right.please suggest me how to solve this

**My code for scroll right-to-left**

```
    horiScrollView.scrollBy(20, 20);
```

please suggest me how to solve this problem.Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the first number negative. the right number doesn't do anything (it's vertical change). First number is how much to move horizontally - so positive numbers mean go right, negative numbers mean go left.

Comment: thanks i done this,Can u please tell me one thing more, i wanna scrooll Horizontalscrollview until button is pressed so what event should i use?

Comment: you want to scroll indefinitely until a button is pressed? or do you want to keep scrolling while the button is pressed?

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem - I have a button of language and by that the `horiScrollView`
sliding is set.

I do that with a new class that extends horizontalScrollView, and there in the `onMesuare` method I set the side by calling  `horiScrollView.scrollBy(20, 20)`, like you did.

In this method, I check if the language is changed, and if so, scroll to the right position I want.
This is the only method I found and it works perfectly.

In that way I also separated the `horizontalScrollView` code from the entire screen, the `horizontalScrollView` in my app in controlling all the screen, so I prefer to make a distinction between the activity and the `horizontalScrollView`.

Answer (score 0):

This code work well for me:

```
mHorScrollView.post(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (rightButton) {
                mHorScrollView.smoothScrollTo(20, 0);
            } else {
                mHorScrollView.smoothScrollTo(-20, 0);
            }
        }
    });
```