# Scroll textview from left to right in android

Tags: android, scroll, textview

I have searched a lot about how to scroll a textview when the text is too large. I found a few samples that helped to make a scrolling textview.

But my problem is that I don't know what should I do to make the scrolling direction from left to right. I mean that, I want the text disappear in right and again appear in from left.

I found a trick here : [How to reverse the direction of marquee of a TextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6704080/how-to-reverse-the-direction-of-marquee-of-a-textview).
But I am looking for a better solution.

Can anyone help me to do this?

Thanks in advance for your attention

Here is the link I found the code["Android automatic horizontally scrolling TextView"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5472362/android-automatic-horizontally-scrolling-textview)

Comment: there are a lot of answers on the web... here is one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14097440/horizontal-scroll-on-textview-on-android you also can found video tutorials on youTube

Comment: @AsfK I think you couldnot understand the question correctly. I said I found samples on how to make a textview scroll horizontally. Now I want to make direction from left to right.

Comment: by default the scroll is from left to right(!) do you mean from right to left? if so, see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28804932/how-to-make-horizontalscrollview-right-to-left-scroll-android. Another answers I found in few seconds: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14105417/android-make-scrollable-view-overflow-to-the-left-instead-of-right and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12842915/scroll-horizontalscrollview-left-right